# Get every category with its sub categories without module

Tags: magento-2.1, category, category-tree, category-listing

I need to get category list with sub categories. I've found multiple solutions that I may need to create a module and get category list inside module's template file. But I need to do this without creating a module. How can I do it?

I tried creating a class and I used those included magento classes in the answers I mentioned with `use` inside my `phtml` file, before declaring my class. but it didn't work.

Is it possible to get every category with its sub categories (and if sub category has its own sub category, I need to get it too ) without creating a module? if so, how can I do it? (I need to do this inside single phtml file)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this...

```
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getName();

    $subCategories = $block->getCategory($category->getId());
    foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
        echo $subCategory->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes an error. $categories = $block->getStoreCategories();

Comment: Please use this inside Magento_Catalog/templates/product/...
any file...